# Parshas Zachor Sfardi versus Ashkenazi

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, four-parshiot

Can a Sefardi be Yotzeh Zachor with an Ashkenazi Laining and vice Versa?

Comment: Given that no one discussed having multiple readings for visitors before 100 years ago, clearly there is no Hava Amina it should be a problem.

Answer (score 8):

Rav Moshe Feinstein writes that all ethnic pronunciations of Hebrew are equally acceptable, even for chalitza which requires the reading of specific Hebrew verses. I'd assume the same would apply here, according to him.

Comment: I have watched a chalitzah with a talmid of Reb MOshe being the Main Dayan and he asked the women which pronunciation she uses and told her to use the one she normally does so I find the Teshuvah intresting

Comment: That way the rabbi knows that what she's saying is correct for her pronunciation, and not a mistake.

Comment: He told her to Pronounce it the way she is used to saying it she was an Isreali in America meaning She Spoke regular and with the Isreali Ivrit accent

Comment: What Shalom is saying is even though Reb Moshe holds that any pronunciation is okay, it still must be consistent to be considered a pronunciation at all. That is why we ask the woman at Halitzah to pronounce it in her normal way.

Comment: Where does he write this?

Answer (score 3):

My LOR/P told me that I can be *yotze* with Ashkenazim as long as the reader differentiates between **ע** and **א** and between **ח** and **כ** (which was the case in my situation).

Answer (score 1):

[Yalkut Yosef (685:12)](http://yalkut.info/%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A2-%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F-%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%94-%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA-%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A8.htm) says Bediavad he is Yose - ומכל מקום אם שומע את קריאת פרשת זכור במבטא אשכנזי, ומתוך ספר תורה בכתב אשכנזי, יצאו ידי חובה.

And also, later on he says an Ashkenazi is also Yose from a Sefaradi.

Answer (score 1):

My friend had it from R Dovid Feinstein that one should look for a reader with his own havarah. In this case the koreh used Israeli, and my friend used sav and komotz.