# With which Torah can one fulfill the obligation of Parshas Zachor?

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, mesorah-tradition, parshat-zachor

There is an argument between texts if the word "Petzua Daka" ([Devarim 23:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%92_%D7%91)) should be with an [Alef](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/5906/jewish/Elul-7.htm) or a Heih. Can someone fulfill his obligation to read Zachor (and normal Torah reading) with a Torah which was written not like his custom?

---

As always, CYLOR.

---

Similar to [Parshas Zachor Sfardi versus Ashkenazi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6400/parshas-zachor-sfardi-versus-ashkenazi) but not exactly.

Comment: @HodofHod, were's your ninja?

Comment: Almost positive Rav Ovadiah Yosef has a teshuva about exactly this topic!

Comment: @DoubleAA see Yabia Omer 6:11:6, and Yechave Daat 6:19.

Comment: @HachamGabriel Also Yechave Daat 6:56 Yabia Omer 8 YD 25 Problem is, where ever he mentions petzua daka he doesn't mention zachor and vice versa.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9205/603

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17381/5

Comment: The Ninja has arrived! *looks around*. Wait, where did everybody go?

Comment: No caution about which Torah to use for Zakhor exists in classical sources like https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%91 so it's pretty clear they didn't care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yalkut Yosef 685:12

> ומתוך ספר תורה בכתב אשכנזי, יצאו ידי חובה
>
> וכן ההיפך, שהכל יוצאים ידי חובה בספר תורה שנכתב בכתב ספרדי, אף שהיו''ד של הצד''י נכתב כיו''ד הפוכה.

a) A Sefaradi who heard from a Ahkenazi **written** Sefer Torah is Yose.

b) An Ashkenazi is also Yose from a Torah **written** in Sefaradi style.

One can infer from the fact the he does not mention the *"petzua daka"* issue, that it would not be a problem (although he doesn't seem to say so explicitly).

Comment: @ShmuelBrill I ***think*** Ashkenazi write it with a Heh. But I'm only 99% sure.