# May one use a Sephardic Torah in an Ashkenaz minyan?

Tags: halacha, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, writing-printing, sefer-torah

May an Ashkenaz minyan use a sephardic torah (written in כתב וועליש) for their minyan or vise versa? Please cite a source

Comment: PM, welcome to Mi Yodeya. Please clarify why you think this might be a problem.

Comment: Presumably inspired by: http://myobiterdicta.blogspot.com/2012/06/american-olim-in-israel-challenge-part_28.html

Comment: Are you only asking because of differences in the ktav (such as kotzot shel yud) or regarding different spellings (such as פצוע דכא/דכה)?

Comment: I'll second SethJ's welcome, and am commenting only to recommend that you [register](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your [account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1668/p-m), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: possible duplicate of [With which Torah can one fulfill the obligation of Parshas Zachor?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14882/with-which-torah-can-one-fulfill-the-obligation-of-parshas-zachor)

Comment: @SethJ, similar, but this is asking about the forms of the letters, and that about "_p'tzua daka_".

Comment: @msh210, it's asking whether one fulfills his obligation with it. Whether it's because of spelling or lettering, I think those same considerations are necessary in order to fully answer either question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Tur Yoreh Deah 274 says in the name of the Rosh](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14272&st=&pgnum=446) that there is no issue with the different lettering. The [Meiri Shabbos 104a](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36401&st=&pgnum=119) also indicates that there is no issue. The [Noda B'Yehuda Yora Deah 171](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1447&pgnum=200) also indicates that it is fine.

Comment: I don't know that the Rosh would accept a yud without a lower-left point. He is just saying that stylistic changes that aren't definitional are OK. But there are lines even he wouldn't cross.

Comment: +1, the _Noda Bihuda_ could not be clearer.

Comment: @DoubleAA, soferim I know say that Sephardim now add kotzo shel yud, et c. ע"פ בעלי התוספות והר׳ יוסף קארו

Comment: @noach that's largely true in mainstream "Sefardi" communities as of the last couple hundred years, but there are still some purists who don't.

Comment: @DoubleAA, are they mostly makpid on getting their own soferim from within their 'edot?

Comment: @noac I don't have any statistics. It may be 99% for all I know but it's not 100%. Yemenites I think even more so are less careful about this issue.

Answer (score 8):

Taken from my answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14886/1035):

> Yalkut Yosef 685:12
>
> > ומתוך ספר תורה בכתב אשכנזי, יצאו ידי חובה
> >
> > וכן ההיפך, שהכל יוצאים ידי חובה בספר תורה שנכתב בכתב ספרדי, אף שהיו''ד של הצד''י נכתב כיו''ד הפוכה.
>
> a) A Sefaradi who heard from a Ahkenazi **written** Sefer Torah is
>   Yose.
>
> b) An Ashkenazi is also Yose from a Torah **written** in Sefaradi
>   style.
>
> One can infer from the fact the he does not mention the *"petzua
>   daka"* issue, that it would not be a problem (although he doesn't seem
>   to say so explicitly).

Therefore, I don't think it's an issue.

Comment: An answer with a link is not very useful to people....I copied your answer from over there, and put it in blockquotes....if you'd like to edit it or change how much is quoted, it's your answer ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Just to throw in a few more modern sources: [Har Tzevi OC 1:32](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20947&st=&pgnum=45), [Minchat Yitzchak 4:47](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1598&st=&pgnum=396&hilite=) and [Mishneh Halachot 7:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1879&st=&pgnum=21&hilite=) all explicitly rule that Vellish is kosher. [Tzitz Eliezer 14:3:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14513&st=&pgnum=20) permits *post facto* even Sta"m that was written with a mix of Vellish and Ashkenazi. [Igrot Moshe OC 5:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&pgnum=49) also permits other forms of writing but he is quick to point out that it is better to stick to one's custom on the matter.

Comment: also orach mishpat (kook) ?:7