# Can an Ashkenazi write a Sephardi Torah?

Tags: halacha, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, mesorah-tradition, safrus

If an Ashkenazi Sofer writes a Sefer Torah in the Sephardi or Yemenite tradition:

a) has he fulfilled his obligation of writing a Sefer Torah (thanks, Double AA!), and

b) since a Sefer Torah must be written LiShmah, is it valid for a Sephardi or Yemenite to use?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17381/5 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14882/5

Comment: May he in terms of what: To fulfill the mitzva of writing a Torah? To avoid lifnei iver to those who read it for the mitzva (if you assume that Ashkenazim view it as pasul)?

Comment: @DoubleAA, Your first point is awesome. I hadn't considered that. I'm going to clarify my question and add that in. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your second point. Why would it not be Lishmah if I'm from a different Eidah?

Comment: @doubleaa, if an Ashkenazi wrote a Sephardi Torah for his own use because he felt it was more correct, then would it be valid? He has a Mesorah, right? We say you have to follow your Mesorah. At what point can one break from his Mesorah if he links up with another? My question is about whether an Ashkenazi's Sephardi Torah is valid generally (ie., not limited to the more specific question about his own use), but this is the train of thought I'm riding.

Comment: I'm still not sure what Lishmah has to do with it. Aren't they all intending to write it Leshem Kedushat Sefer Torah?

Comment: @doubleaa how can you do something LiShmah against your Mesorah? Or can you?

Comment: I don't see why not, providing you really are trying to fulfill the mitzva. Maybe it will turn out that you didn't succeed because of Mesora issues. But you had the right kavana. Lishmah is really one of the simplest kavanot to have.

Comment: Is this the kind of thing you are looking for? http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&pgnum=49

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm not really sure. It definitely _seems_ related, but I can't quite figure out whether that makes it ok or not.

Answer (score 4):

Chacham Ovadia in his Yachaveh Daas chelek 2:3 writes that a sefardi sefer Torah is good for an ashkanazi and a ashkanazi sefer Torah is kosher for a Sefardi. This is in the actual Torah itself (the ksav),so if one would write either one he would get a mitzvah of ksivas sefer Torah. Regarding reading from the Torah(nothing to do with the ksav only the pronunciation) Chacham Ovadia in Yechaveh Daas 6:19 writes that by parshas zachor one should **hear** it in his pronunciation because it is a doraisa and there is a discussion on this.