# An Ashkenaz-Sefaradi couple is getting married, can they reuse their mezuzot?

Tags: halacha, marriage, mezuzah

An Ashkenazi and Sefaradi (Edot Hamizrach) are getting married. They each have available mezuzot from previous houses they lived in, written in Ashkenazi (Beit Yosef) or Sefaradi (Vellish) script.

Are there halachic sources commenting on whether they can hang these mezuzot in their new dwelling independently of the script of the *mezuza*? Do they have to follow the husband's custom or can they also reuse the wife's *mezuzot*?

Does it matter if they are moving into a new apartment (without *mezuzot*) vs. the apartment of one of them which already has *mezuzot*? In the latter case, does it matter if it is the husband's or wife's apartment?

PS. This [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18334/11501) is related but appears to be asking *bdieved* and without the (potential) attenuating fact of different customs for husband and wife.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on which of the two rabbis you ask? 

Comment: @mbloch Is she keeping her customs or switching? If the latter, what is special about this case compared to any other case of having the "wrong" mezuzot already? If the former, how is this different from roommates where one lived there first?

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't realize there was a choice in customs for what relates to the couple. I thought a wife had to take her husband's customs beyond what she does alone for herself. And again, are you saying a woman switching customs has to switch mezuzot? That is not obvious to me once they are installed. You yourself brought an Igrot Moshe that might show one doesn't have to do this (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17411/11501)

Comment: I didn't say there was a choice. I'm just considering the two possible situations. I am not saying a woman switching customs has to switch mezuzot. I'm saying her case is clearly the exact same as anyone else who has the "wrong" mezuzot up. My point is this question is just the same old question as always, or at least no one has provided any reason to think otherwise. I'd move to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @DoubleAA I understand. So you are saying if she is not switching customs, she has nothing to do. If she is, then her case is the same as anyone else in the same situation. That might be the answer. I don't know that it was so simple but that already helps. Thanks

Comment: @mbloch If she isn't switching customs, you can still ask if the husband is allowed to use her mezuzot since he lives there too, but that's the same as any other roommate-question.

Answer (score -2):

The custom is that the household follows the custom of the husband.  If the husband is Sephardic, they use his mezuzot, and they go straight up, not tilted, and the wife may eat kitniot on Pessah. That is my experience.  I don't know if it's halacha.