# Inconsistent sifrei Torah for the required number of aliyos

Tags: torah-reading, sefer-torah, mesorah-tradition, contradiction

Different groups (Ashkenazim, Sefaradim, Teimonim) have different traditions for spellings of different words in the Torah.  Practically, while each group writes according to their own mesorah, we consider any of the traditions valid and [can use any of them](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14886/11532), even for Parshas Zachor.

What about days where the required number of aliyos are read from different Sifrei Torah, like Ch"m Pesach or Rosh Chodesh Chanukah?  Can you read e.g. the first three aliyos from an Ashkenazi Torah and the last one from a Sefaradi Torah?  Or is this a contradiction, since you're definitely not reading the required number of aliyos from a correct Sefer Torah?

What about Shabbos Rosh Chodesh Chanuka, Shekalim, or Hachodesh, where you have exactly one Ashkenazi, one Sefaradi, and one Teimoni Sefer Torah?  Is it required or preferable to add aliyos so that you read 7 from the same Sefer Torah, or does it not matter?  <sup><sub>(Or Simchas Torah, but then you're probably adding aliyos anyway.)</sub></sup>

Comment: A couple hundred years ago before communities settled on these three versions, this would happen essentially every holiday, since different spellings were more common even in the same shul, depending what book a given scribe copied from

Comment: I've never ever heard of changing a Torah during the reading (except for a discovered error). For the second question it would be good to know where are these very few differences (I remember one ה-א pair), because your example may not be relevant.

Comment: @Kazi it doesn't matter if the spelling change is in that reading or not. The problem is the Torah is "pasul"

Comment: Similar sort of question but for Rambam/Rosh parsha breaks http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=275&pgnum=5

Comment: @Kazi What did you mean by "your example may not be relevant"?

Comment: I didn't know all the spelling differences in _Sifrei Torah,_ but it seems to me that 99% percent is about whether using the short or the long form, so the actual pronunciation doesn't change (or [ה-א](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0523.htm#2)). If I understand it correctly, the only pronunciation altering difference is in [Noach](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0109.htm#29). Should there be more such, it would be problematic to mix them, otherwise why would it be relevant?

Comment: @Kazi Why does pronunciation matter here?